# SSH Equivalent on Windows

Tags: asp.net, windows, ssh, cygwin

I am making an Asp.Net application which does the following on the client computer:

- Establish a Connection
- Check client's cpu usage to see if it is idle or not
- if the client is idle it starts executing a c application
- while executing the script if client starts doing something (also checked by monitoring his cpu usage) stop signal is sent
- start signal is again sent to the client if he is back to his idle position

If the client is Ubuntu, I use ssh and execute what I want to. What is the way of doing this in Windows without the root access.

thanks in advance for replying.

Comment: No proper understanding of what you are looking for

Comment: What prevents you from installing SSH server on Windows?

Comment: i can't install anything on the client computer. Though i can do anything on the server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds a bit dodgy to me.  However, what you are looking for is called PsExec (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553)

**UPDATE**

The only other way I can think of doing this is to use the built in task scheduler for windows.

With the task scheduler you can set a task to start when a computer has been idle for a particular amount of time and pause or stop it when it ceases to be idle.

Once the task is installed, just forget about it.

Comment: Thanks. I hope this helps. But it doesn't include a way to send signals to pause and continue a job.

Comment: @w2lame: you're right, it doesn't have signaling per se.  You could have the app that is remotely started implement it's own communication back to your controller to decide whether to continue or not.

Comment: But i cannot modify the application code because there is an abstraction layer which prevents me from doing so. Is there any other utility which can help me in this.

Comment: You can try using http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/pausep.aspx, which is a utility that pauses all of the threads in a process.  Installing it on the remote machine and PsExec'ing it should work.

Comment: thanks. i hope this should work. Only trick remains is to get it working properly with asp.net . will update after trying it practically. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try SSH FTP or SFTP is analogous to SSH in windows

Comment: 1 for making mistakes and insisting on them. SFTP stands for "SSH File Transfer Protocol", but it's not FTP (as in RFC 959). SFTP is a binary protocol, while FTP is a text one.

Comment: @all : do answer the guy w2lame's question